# Union of one set of outer measure zero and one set of outer measure $\geq 0$ has outer measure zer0.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove directly from the definition of Outer Measure $m^{*}$ that if $m^{*}(A) = 0$, then $m^{*}(A \cup B)=m^{*}(B)$ (this is actually an exercise from Royden, but our professor wants us to use the definition of Outer Measure (a function $m^{*}: \{\text{subsets of}\,\mathbb{R}\} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \cup \{\infty \}$ defined as:

> $m^{*}(A) = \inf \left \{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_{k})\, \vert I_{1},I_{2},\cdots \text{open bounded intervals such that}\, A \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k} \right\}$ (where $l(I_{k})$ is the length of the $k$th interval)).

Now, let $m^{*}(B) =  \inf \left \{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(J_{k})\, \vert J_{1},J_{2},\cdots \text{open bounded intervals such that}\, B \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} J_{k} \right\}$ and $m^{*}(A \cup B) = \inf \left \{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(M_{k})\, \vert M_{1},M_{2},\cdots \text{open bounded intervals such that}\, A \cup B \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} M_{k} \right\}$

The way I think the proof should go is the following:

> $m^{*}(A \cup B) = \inf \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(M_{k}) = \inf \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l(I_{k}) + \inf \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l(J_{k}) = 0 + m^{*}(B) = m^{*}(B)$.

However, in order to do this, I would (1) need to show that $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} M_{k} = (\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}I_{k})\cup (\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}J_{k})$ and (2) that this implies that $\inf \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(M_{k}) = \inf\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l(I_{k}) + \inf\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l(J_{k})$.

It's frustrating, too, because this is supposed to be an easy exercise, and intuitively, it makes sense that the absolute minimum needed to cover $A \cup B$ should also be the absolute minimum needed to cover $A$ plus the absolute minimum needed to cover $B$, but I need to show this in a mathematically rigorous way, and can't just assert things without being able to mathematically explain them.

If someone could please help me fill in the justification gaps in this proof and/or fix it if it's incorrect, it would be very much appreciated, and would definitely help me in my attempts to tackle the harder problems.

Comment: You have to prove $m*(A\cup B)\ge m*(B)$ and $m*(A\cup B)\le m*(B).$ Which inequality are you stuck on?

Comment: $m^{*}(A \cup B) \leq m^{*}(B)$. That's really all I need to show here? 

What about showing that $\inf \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(M_{k}) = \inf \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l(I_{k}) + \inf \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l(J_{k})$? How do I prove that?

Comment: Do you know how to prove from the definition of outer measure that $m^*(A\cup B)\le m^*(A)+m^*(B)$? Doesn't the proof of that general fact work in the special case where $m^*(A)=0$?

Comment: To show $m^*(A\cup B)\le m^*(B)$ it's enough to show that, for every $\varepsilon\gt0$, you have $m^*(A\cup B)\le m^*(B)+\varepsilon.$

Comment: I'm going to try to prove, using the definition of outer measure, that $m^{*}(A \cup B) \leq m^{*}(A)+m^{*}(B)$. I'll let you know how it goes! Thanks :)

Comment: Let $\varepsilon\gt0$ be given. Can you find intervals $I_k$ covering $A$ and intervals $J_k$ covering $B$ so that $\sum l(I_k)\lt\varepsilon/2$ and $\sum l(J_k)\lt m^*(B)+\varepsilon/2$?

Comment: @bof How is $\sum l(J_{k}) < m^{*}(B) + \epsilon/2$ when by definition, $m^{*}(B) \leq \inf \sum I(J_{k}) \leq \sum I(J_{k})$?

Comment: The statement $a=\inf S$ does not just say that $a$ is a lower bound for $S,$ it says that $a$ is the ***greatest*** lower bound for $S.$ Hence, if $\varepsilon\gt0,$ then, since $a+\varepsilon$ can ***not*** be a lower bound for $S,$ there exists $s\in S$ such that $s\lt a+\varepsilon.$

Comment: @bof, based on the help you've given me, I am going to submit an answer for this question. Could you please look it over and comment on whether it is okay, or if anything needs to be fixed? (I am especially concerned about whether it is valid to say that because it holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, it holds for $\epsilon = 0$.) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My solution doesn't use the definition of the outer measure, but it goes as follows:

First, since $m^*(A) =0$. Then, $$m^*(A \cup B) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B) \leq m^*(B).$$
It suffices to show that $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B)$. We need to consider three cases.

---

If $A = \emptyset$, then $A \cup B = B$ and $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(B)$.

---

If $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq B$, then $A \cup B = B$ and $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(B)$.

---

If $\emptyset \neq A \nsubseteq  B$, then $B \subset A \cup B$ and $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B)$.

---

As you can see all the three cases gives $m^*(B) \leq m^*(A \cup B)$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ has infinite outer measure, the equality holds trivially.

So, suppose instead that $m^{*}(B) < \infty$.

For $B$, let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, $\exists$ a countable collection $\{I_{B,i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ of open, bounded intervals for which $B \subseteq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}I_{B,i}$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(I_{B,i})<m^{*}(B) + \epsilon/2$ (since, by definition of $m^{*}$ as an outer measure, $m^{*}(B) = \inf \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(I_{B,i})$, $m^{*}(B)+\epsilon/2$ cannot be a lower bound for $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(I_{B,i})$, so we must have that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(I_{B,i})<m^{*}(B) + \epsilon/2$.

Similarly, for $A$, we have that for $\epsilon > 0$, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(I_{A,i}) < m^{*}(A)+\epsilon/2 < 0 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon/2$.

Now, for greater ease of notation, let $A:=E_{1}$ and $B:=E_{2}$. Then, we have $m^{*}\left( \sum_{k=1}^{2}E_{k}\right) = \inf \left\{\sum_{1\leq k \leq 2, \,i < \infty}l(I_{k,i}) \right\} = \sum_{1\leq k \leq 2, \,i < \infty}l(I_{k,i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} l(I_{1},i) + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} l(I_{2},i) < (m^{*}(E_{1})+\epsilon/2) + (m^{*}(E_{2})+\epsilon/2) = (0 + \epsilon/2) + (m^{*}(E_{2})+\epsilon/2) = m^{*}(E_{2}) + \epsilon$.

Since this holds $\forall \epsilon > 0$, it also holds for $\epsilon = 0$.

Now, we must show that $m^{*}(B) = 0 + m^{*}(B) = m^{*}(A) + m^{*}(B) \leq m^{*}(A \cup B)$.

For ease of notation, again let $A = E_{1}$, $B=E_{2}$. Then, $m^{*}(E_{2})=0+m^{*}(E_{2}) = m^{*}(E_{1}) + m^{*}(E_{2}) = \inf \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(I_{1,i}) \right\} +  \inf \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(I_{2,i}) \right\} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} l(I_{1,i}) + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}l(I_{2,i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[ l(I_{1,i}) + l(I_{2,i})\right] = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq 2,\,i<\infty}l(I_{k,i}) $

Now, $m^{*}(E_{1} \cup E_{2}) = \inf \left\{\sum_{1 \leq j \leq 2,\,i<\infty}l(I_{k,i})  \right\}$, so $m^{*}(E_{1} \cup E_{2})+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon > 0$, cannot be a lower bound for $\sum_{1 \leq j \leq 2,\,i<\infty}l(I_{k,i})$.

Thus, our inequality above becomes $< m^{*}(E_{1}\cup E_{2})+\epsilon$.

Since this holds $\forall \epsilon > 0$, it also holds for $\epsilon = 0$.

Comment: @bof, what do you think?